# Как повернуть стрелку?

Tags: html, css

Собственно не могу понять, как её повернуть так, чтобы она была вверх?
Менял transform, но не могу понять, как он работает. Добивался нужного результата когда указывал больше 100% в transform-origin, но это, как я понимаю, не совсем правильное решение.

```css
.prev {
  position: relative;
}
.prev:before,
.prev:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 32px;
  background: #4a275c;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.prev:before {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.prev:after {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="prev"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поворот линий:

1. Располагаем линии абсолютно, чтобы и `before`, и `after` распогались друг на друге;
2. Исходя из высоты блоков в `8px` предполагаем, что линии у нас - толщиной в `4px` и начинаются они не с `0 0`, а с `4px 4px`. Корректируем `transform-origin`;
3. Смещаем обе линии ближе к середине блока, и поворачиваем - одну на 45 градусов (правую), другую на 135 градусов (левую).

Код:

```css
.prev {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  width: 44px;
}
.prev:before,
.prev:after {
  background: #4a275c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 4px 4px;
  width: 32px;
}
.prev:before {
  transform: translate(18px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.prev:after {
  transform: translate(18px, 0) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="prev"></div>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/83gc9td3/)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

Делаем:

```
.prev {
 display: inline-block; /* Здесь и происходит магия */
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: да, можно так сделать, но мне интересно не как повернуть родитель, а как поставить сами линии должным образом. всё равно спасибо за отклик